# SpriteKit getting error regarding UIElements when transitioning to new scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Hello I am working on a `SpriteKit` game in Swift that right now only has two scenes, a loading scene and the game scene. The game scene reaches out to a database to get info before it is presented. Everything in the game scene works great. I am running into issues when I go to the loading scene first instead of straight to the game scene. Through call backs I tell the loading scene to present the game scene once it is done doing the database stuff. However when I try presenting I get 10+ of these massive errors:

> 2015-11-12 09:48:33.880 SpaceAcademy[2373:764586] This application is
>   modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can
>   lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an
>   exception in a future release. (followed by a bunch of random info)

Now through some testing I have figured out that its my `UIElement` such as buttons, sliders, and labels that are causing this. But I moved them into the `didMoveToView` function so I am confused why they are still throwing errors because they are in the "background thread"..

Also something odd is that these aren't fatal errors. My console just blows up and the `UIElements` show up after a ten second delay. Something else odd is that if I tap where I know the button is supposed to be the function is still called as if the button was actually there.

I would greatly appreciate a solution to get rid of the console explosion but more importantly get rid of the ten second delay of the `UI Elements` showing up, Thanks!!

Code Setting up Scenes

```
let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = false
    skView.showsNodeCount = false
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill


    let loading = LoadingScene(size: view.bounds.size, newScene: scene)
    skView.presentScene(loading, transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1))

    scene.setEverythingUp(loading)
```

The loading Scene:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class LoadingScene:SKScene{
    var newScene:SKScene!
    var oldCount = 0
    var loadCount = 0{
    didSet{
        print(loadCount)
        if loadCount == 0{
            if oldCount == 1{
                self.view?.presentScene(newScene)
            }
        }
        oldCount = loadCount
    }
}

init(size: CGSize, newScene:SKScene) {
    self.newScene = newScene
    super.init(size: size)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    let imageArray = [
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "Loader/Loader1.png"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "Loader/Loader2.png"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "Loader/Loader3.png")
    ]

    let loader = SKSpriteNode(texture: imageArray[0])
    let animation = SKAction.animateWithTextures(imageArray, timePerFrame: 0.33)
    loader.runAction(SKAction.scaleBy(0.25, duration: 0))
    loader.zPosition = 100
    loader.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(animation))
    loader.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
    self.addChild(loader)
}

func start(){
    self.loadCount = self.loadCount + 1
}

func end(){
    self.loadCount = self.loadCount - 1
}

}
```

Code from GameScene:

```
func setEverythingUp(myLoadingScene: LoadingScene){

    let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    var Id = 0
    if let tempID = defaults.objectForKey("UserId") as? Int {
       Id = tempID
    }else{
        print("newUser")
        defaults.setObject(0, forKey: "UserId")
        defaults.synchronize()
    }

    self.mySettings = Settings(UserId: Id)
    self.myURLRequests = URLRequests(thesettings: self.mySettings)

    ///////////call back system here, start() increments number of tasks waiting to finish, end() means a task is finished

    myLoadingScene.start()
    myURLRequests.getFleet(self, UserId: self.mySettings.UserId, enemy: false){ () -> () in
        myLoadingScene.end()
    }

    myLoadingScene.start()
    myURLRequests.getFleet(self, UserId: self.mySettings.UserId, enemy: true){ () -> () in
        myLoadingScene.end()
    }



    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    addStars()


    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:self.size.width/2, y:self.size.height/2)
    self.myCamera.position = CGPointMake(200, 0)
    self.addChild(self.myCamera)
    self.camera = self.myCamera
    self.myAnchor.position = self.myCamera.position
}



override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    print("in view")

    let pinch = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("PinchScale:"))
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("Tap:"))
    let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("DragMove:"))

    self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(pinch)
    self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(pan)


    let fireButton = UIButton(type: .System)
    fireButton.setTitle("Fire!", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    fireButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "TrebuchetMS", size: 70)
    fireButton.sizeToFit()
    fireButton.frame = CGRect(x: self.size.width*0.5 - 80, y: 20, width: self.size.width*0.3, height: 30)
    fireButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("FireButtonClicked"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view?.addSubview(fireButton)

    let alternateControls = false

    let AngleLabel = UILabel()
    AngleLabel.text = "Angle"
    AngleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "TrebuchetMS", size: 30)
    AngleLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()


    let AngleSlider = UISlider()
    AngleSlider.addTarget(self, action: Selector("AngleSlided:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    AngleSlider.maximumValue = 90
    AngleSlider.minimumValue = -90
    AngleSlider.value = 0
    AngleSlider.continuous = true



    let PowerLabel = UILabel()
    PowerLabel.text = "Power"
    PowerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "TrebuchetMS", size: 30)
    PowerLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()


    let PowerSlider = UISlider()
    PowerSlider.addTarget(self, action: Selector("PowerSlided:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    PowerSlider.maximumValue = 0.99
    PowerSlider.minimumValue = 0.1
    PowerSlider.value = 0.5
    PowerSlider.continuous = true


    if alternateControls{
        AngleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: self.size.width*0.05, y: 10, width: self.size.width*0.3, height: 60)
        AngleSlider.frame = CGRect(x: self.size.width * -0.05, y: self.size.height*0.55, width: self.size.height*0.7, height: 30)
        AngleSlider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI) * 1.5)
        PowerLabel.frame = CGRect(x: self.size.width*0.7, y: 10, width: self.size.width*0.3, height: 60)
        PowerSlider.frame = CGRect(x: self.size.width * 0.65, y: self.size.height*0.55, width: self.size.height*0.7, height: 30)
        PowerSlider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI) * 1.5)
    }else{
        AngleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: self.size.width*0.21, y: self.size.height-80, width: self.size.width*0.3, height: 60)
        AngleSlider.frame = CGRect(x: self.size.width * 0.025, y: self.size.height-30, width: self.size.width*0.45, height: 30)
        PowerLabel.frame = CGRect(x: self.size.width*0.71, y: self.size.height-80, width: self.size.width*0.3, height: 60)
        PowerSlider.frame = CGRect(x: self.size.width * 0.525, y: self.size.height-30, width: self.size.width*0.45, height: 30)
    }

    self.view?.addSubview(AngleLabel)
    self.view?.addSubview(AngleSlider)
    self.view?.addSubview(PowerLabel)
    self.view?.addSubview(PowerSlider)

}
```

Comment: removing the UIElements removed half the errors, but theres still about 8 or so

Comment: What is a UIElement? I don't see any reference to UIElement in the code you posted. AutoLayout is a UIKit feature, what you're showing is SpriteKit.

Comment: UIButton, UILabel, ect

Comment: OK, those are known as UIViews. Post your UIKit code. You posted code referencing SpriteKit, and that isn't generating autolayout warnings. In particular, are you adding or removing UIViews in a background thread? Where do you have background threads? Perhaps in a network response handler?

Comment: "Through call backs I tell the loading scene to present the game scene once it is done doing the database stuff." Let's see those callbacks and how they are invoked. There's a good chance that's where your issue lies.

Comment: Let's see the code where you're presenting the game scene...

Comment: ok added requested code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
myURLRequests.getFleet(self, UserId: self.mySettings.UserId, enemy: false){ () -> () in
    myLoadingScene.end()
}
```

Which presumably calls `myLoadingScene.end()` on a background thread once the URL request is complete. `end` sets `loadCount`, which has a setter that starts the new view, `self.view?.presentScene(newScene)`

It's this last piece that needs to run on the main thread.

Let's say you had a handy function to run something on the main thread:

```
func on_main_async (closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        closure()
    }
}
```

Then you could change the scene presentation code to

```
on_main_async() { self.view?.presentScene(newScene) }
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: awesome! works perfect! only had to change 'newScene' to 'self.newScene'

Comment: Great! Glad it worked! I hope you now have a better understanding of the differences between UIKit/autolayout & SceneKit.